# Change file extension with javascript if URL has Querystring after it

Tags: javascript, regex, svg

I use this nice piece of code here to replace all .svg files with .png's in older browsers, fantastic for backwards compatibility.

However, been using shopify today and it, for some fantastic reason, it adds a query strong to the end of every asset it pulls from the CDN.

```
function supportsSVG() {
    return !! document.createElementNS && !! document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg').createSVGRect;
}

if (!supportsSVG()) {
    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var dotSVG = /.*\svg$/;
    for (var i = 0; i !== imgs.length; ++i) {
        if(imgs[i].src.match(dotSVG)) {
            imgs[i].src = imgs[i].src.slice(0, -8) + 'png';
        }
    }
}
```

Now that targets img's with .svg at the end. But I can't figure out how to target .svg?1234 and replace svg with .png

Anyone know the regex to target that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works even if the domain name is .svg or there's any other .svg in the URL. It takes the last .svg

```
var url = "http://tricky.href.svg/filename.svg?abc1?test2?test3";
url = url.replace(/\.(svg)($|\?)/, '.png$2');
console.log(url); // http://tricky.href.svg/filename.png?abc1?test2?test3
```

You can use it like this:

```
var dotSVG = /\.(svg)($|\?)/;
for (var i = 0; i !== imgs.length; ++i) {
    imgs[i].src = imgs[i].src.replace(dotSVG, '.png$2');
}
```

Comment: Perfect, i took the `/\.(svg)($|\?)/` and used that in my snippet. Finds and replaces fantastically :)

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Make sure to use the `$2` in `'.png$2'`. It will replace the `$2` with either `?` or blank if it is at the end of the url string.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus You probably shouldn't strip the last part after the ? as it prevents returning stale files from the CDN. In other words, a drop in replacement of the regex is probably not a good idea. I've updated the answer using `replace()`. Also, it would only do the replacement if it matches so there's no need for an extra `if`.

Comment: Thank you for amending your answer, that makes more sense to add the ? back onto it to make it work and not be an old file